# Change color of individual items of array in React

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs

I have fetched and displayed a list of json data:
[What it currently looks like in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNJKW.png)

I want to be able to change the background color of these buttons based on the value of the property in my json file, 'era'. If composer.era === 'Renaissance', setColor('red'). If composer.era === 'Baroque', setColor('blue'), etc...

Here is some of my json for reference:

```
{
    "name": "Giulio Caccini",
    "img": "/composerImgs/Caccini.jpeg",
    "era": "Baroque",
    "id": 23
},
{
    "name": "Giovanni Gabrieli",
    "img": "/composerImgs/Gabrieli.jpeg",
    "era": "Renaissance",
    "id": 24
},
```

Here is the fetch request from that json and how I'm currently handling it:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Login } from './Login'
import { Timeline } from './Timeline'
import { Results } from './Results'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import './App.css'
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'

const ComposerButton = styled('button')({
  width: '12rem',
  height: '12rem',
  position: 'relative',
  right: '1rem',
  border: 'none',
  borderRadius: '25px'
})

 const App = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [composers, setComposers] = useState([]);
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#27856a')
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchComposers = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('composers.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      
      const listofComposers = data.composers.map((composer) => {
      
        return (
          <Link to='/results'>
          <ComposerButton style={{backgroundColor: color}} onClick={() => setName(composer.name)} key={composer.id}>
              <ComposerName>{composer.name}</ComposerName>
              {/* <ComposerImg src={composer.img}/> */}
          </ComposerButton>
          </Link>
        )
     })
     setComposers(listofComposers);
    }

    fetchComposers();
  }, []);

  return (

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Login code={code} />} />
          <Route path='/timeline' element={<Timeline composers={composers} />} />
          <Route path='/results' element={<Results name={name} code={code}  />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I change `color` depending on `composer.era`'s value?
I've already tried:

```
  const listofComposers = data.composers.map((composer) => {

        if (composer.era === 'Renaissance'){
              setColor('red')
        }
        if (composer.era === 'Baroque'){
              setColor('blue')
        }
        etc...
```

Comment: @jsN00b That worked! Thank you!

Comment: @jsN00b the first answer (by making an object) works perfectly. The second answer would require me to change other parts of my app.

Comment: Okay, cool. As long as it's worked for you, all's good. Enjoy ! :-)